# Is there a way to change the 'Advanced Permissions' of a file in Windows using command line?

Tags: windows, windows-10, permissions, icacls

So just to clarify: I would like to remove the advanced permission called "Change permissions" because even if you remove permissions from a group (in this case administrators) using `icacls`, while no one in the group can edit or delete the target file, they can still go into file properties and edit the permissions to give themselves back *Full* or *Modify* or whatnot.

I don't want to go off the rails on questions like *'Why do you want to remove these permissions from the computer's administrators?'* so suffice it to say that I have left SYSTEM with Full control and I manage everything I need via a service that runs as LOCAL SYSTEM so basically there is still access to the file, but the way I need it to be accessed.

I just can't find in the `iCacls` syntax anything that allows me to modify the *'Advanced'* permissions which is where the *'Change Permissions'* item is.

Comment: "if you remove permissions from a group (in this case administrators)" Administrators can always undo something set by an Administrator. That's why they are called Administrators! ;)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's right there in the `icacls /?` help screen:

```
    perm is a permission mask and can be specified in one of two forms:
        a sequence of simple rights:
                [...]
        a comma-separated list in parentheses of specific rights:
                DE - delete
                RC - read control
                WDAC - write DAC
                WO - write owner
                S - synchronize
                AS - access system security
                MA - maximum allowed
                GR - generic read
                GW - generic write
                GE - generic execute
                GA - generic all
                RD - read data/list directory
                WD - write data/add file
                AD - append data/add subdirectory
                REA - read extended attributes
                WEA - write extended attributes
                X - execute/traverse
                DC - delete child
                RA - read attributes
                WA - write attributes
        inheritance rights may precede either form and are applied
        only to directories:
                (OI) - object inherit
                (CI) - container inherit
                (IO) - inherit only
                (NP) - don't propagate inherit
                (I) - permission inherited from parent container
```

These are the generic names for all 'advanced' permissions that you see. "Change permissions" is called "Write DAC" because it allows one to write/modify the Discretionary Access Control List.

The included examples specifically mention this permission:

```
        icacls file /grant Administrator:(D,WDAC)
        - Will grant the user Administrator Delete and Write DAC
          permissions to file.

        icacls file /grant *S-1-1-0:(D,WDAC)
        - Will grant the user defined by sid S-1-1-0 Delete and
          Write DAC permissions to file.
```

You can do the opposite of the above example and explicitly `/deny` them the WDAC permission.

However, remember that the permissions scheme has two safety nets:

- The file's *owner* can always change its permissions, bypassing any "deny write-DAC" permission entries. If you don't want Administrators to be able to give themselves additional permissions, make sure the file isn't owned by Administrators (e.g. set its owner to SYSTEM).
- Administrators are granted SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege and can always change a file's ownership, bypassing any "deny write-owner" permission entries. If you don't want Administrators to be able to do this... well, they're *Administrators*, they own the whole system already.